# Windows Time won't synchronize

Tags: windows-7, windows, time

I'm actually working on a client machine and i have a problem with the Windows Time Service.
The Operating system is Windows 7.
I have to synchronyze the Hour but i got systematically a timeout error.

Here's the entire message :

> An error occured while Windows was synchronizing with
>   time.windows.com. This operation returned because the timeout period
>   expired.

The Windows Firewall is disabled.

Port 123 allowed on the Cisco router (Working on the others machines of the network, sync OK).

The server was not include in Active Directory.

Windows Time Local Group Policy set to Not Configured.

I tried with multiple NTP servers :

- 0.fr.pool.ntp.org
- 1.fr.pool.ntp.org
- 2.fr.pool.ntp.org
- 3.fr.pool.ntp.org
- time.windows.com
- time.nist.gov

And always the same message.

Here's what i tried :

In first i unreg/reg the w32tm service :

```
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
```

And then reboot

Next i tried to query the ntp server :

```
C:\Windows\system32>net time \\time.windows.com /set /yes
The service has not been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2184.
```

Tried to manually add a peer :

```
C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com
The command completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /config /update
The command completed successfully.
```

And when i resync/rediscover, here is the Output :

```
C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /resync /rediscover
Sending resync command to local computer
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

Output of Status :

```
C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /status
Leap Indicator: 3(last minute has 61 seconds)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
Precision: -6 (15.625ms per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0000000s
Root Dispersion: 0.0000000s
ReferenceId: 0x00000000 (unspecified)
Last Successful Sync Time: unspecified
Source: Local CMOS Clock
Poll Interval: 6 (64s)
```

Output of configuration :

```
C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /configuration
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Policy)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Policy)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Policy)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Policy)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Policy)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Policy)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Policy)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Policy)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Policy)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Policy)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Policy)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Policy)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Policy)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Policy)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Policy)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 604800 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: 0.fr.pool.ntp.org,0x8 (Local)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

I don't really know what to do next or if i'm doing it wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS : Excuse my bad english.